# Plot certain range of values with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib

I have parsed out data form .json than plotted them but I only wants a certain range from it
e.g. year-mounth= 2014-12to 2020-03
THE CODE IS

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_json("observed-solar-cycle-indices.json", orient='records')
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(data)

x = data['time-tag']
y = data['ssn']

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlabel('Year-day'), plt.ylabel('SSN')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result, as you can see it is too many
[image: 1]

here is the json file: https://services.swpc.noaa.gov/json/solar-cycle/observed-solar-cycle-indices.json
How to either parse out certain value from the JSON file or plot a certain range?

Comment: What do you mean by "e.g. year-date = 2014-314 to 2020-083", shouldn't year go max to 2014-012 if the format is Year-Months?

Comment: Sorry, the format is Year-Day

Comment: Are you sure? I have loaded your json file you referred to. Checking `data['time-tag']`, I see years going from yyyy-01 to yyyy-12. You can verify this using `data[data['time-tag'].str.contains('1900')]`, fill-in for 1900 any year you like.

Comment: Hi Jirapat, does the answer work for you?

Comment: so sorry, you were right its Year - months

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

Select the data using a start and end date

```
ndata = data[ (data['time-tag'] > '2014-01') & (data['time-tag'] < '2020-12')]
```

Plot the data. The x-axis labeling is adapted to display only every 12th label

```
x = ndata['time-tag']
y = ndata['ssn']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

every_nth = 12
for n, label in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)

plt.xlabel('Year-Month') 
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel('SSN')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do a search for the index value of your start and end dates for both x and y values. Use this to create a smaller set of lists that you can plot.

For example, it might be something like

```
x = data['time-tag']
y = data['ssn']

start_index = x.index('2014-314')
end_index = x.index('2020-083')

x_subsection = x[start_index : end_index]
y_subsection = y[start_index : end_index]

plt.plot(x_subsection, y_subsection, 'o')
plt.xlabel('Year-day'), plt.ylabel('SSN')
plt.show()
```

You may need to convert the dataframe into an array with np.array().

Comment: I ran the script and got this error:  x = data['time-tag']
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.